# Show next object with specific class after focus lost with jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have (I think) a simple problem. I'm building application with Asp.net and I want to show something (for example "!!!") after user left empty textbox. I cannot use standard validation components in Asp.net because it blocks every postback.

My attempt:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.validation-control-is-not-empty').focusout(function () {
                if ($(this).val() === '') {
                    $(this).next('.validation-alert').show();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).next('.validation-alert').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h1>Validation test</h1>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TbName" CssClass="validation-control-is-not-empty" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="validation-alert" style="display: none;">!!!</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TbMessage" CssClass="validation-control-is-not-empty" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="validation-alert" style="display: none;">!!!</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Focus lost is calling my function but the problem is that this:

> $(this).next('.validation-alert')

will not find the next needed object... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.validation-alert` is not the next sibling of `.validation-control-is-not-empty`, they are the children of same `tr`, so you can find the `tr` parent of `this` and then find the `.validation-alert` element within it.

```
$('.validation-control-is-not-empty').focusout(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.validation-alert').show();
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.validation-alert').hide();
    }
});
```

---

You can shorten it using .toggle() like

```
$('.validation-control-is-not-empty').focusout(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.validation-alert').toggle($(this).val() === '');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4x9gbexj/)